# Running an application with root (or admin) privilages

Tags: macos, root, mamp

I want to run MAMP Pro as root (or admin) under Mac OS X. MAMP starts up an Apache server on port 80 and because it's a low port, it I have to type my password in every time I start it up or shut it down.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Edit the sudoers file and add an entry:

```
sudo visudo

joshk ALL=NOPASSWD: /path/to/apache2
```

Answer (score 1):

Do you need Apache on port 80?

If this is the only part that requires administrative permissions, it might be easiest (and safer) to just [configure another port](http://www.mamp.info/en/documentation/faq.html#q11).

Comment: I'd really really like it to be on port 80, how's that? ;)